# cURL login : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: php, curl, asp-classic

I've searched my problem.
Questions similar to the problem was too much, but I could not get to any conclusion.

I have written the following code

```
<?php

$aPosts = array("__VIEWSTATE" => "/wEPDwULLTEwMDM5MDE3NDUPZBYEZg8VARJTYWZhcmFmYXJpbi1TZXBlaHJkAgEPZBYEAgUPEA8WAh4LXyFEYXRhQm91bmRnZGRkZAINDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaBYCZg9kFgJmDxUBE9io2K7YtNmG2KfZhdmHINmH2KdkZMdboHK0C5vwU/0H8jDKN8JIUGAWK7y6psPERPkF/dYP",
                "__EVENTVALIDATION" => "/wEWBwLVs6iwDQKl1bK4CQK1qbSRCwLHlbuRCALGla+RCAKC3IeGDAKqs9XKA+XnuPlm+7BeBMKdG9tnXAq2MVVFKjVmbCbQG4g9jB9u",
                "txtUsername" => "",
                "txtPassword" => "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
                "dplLanguage" => "en",
                "btnPublicLogin" => "login",
);
$posts = "";
foreach($aPosts as $key => $value){
    $posts .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
}

$url="http://www.example.com/login.aspx";
$cookie="cookiew.txt";
$rnd = rand(2547896321456987, 9999999999999999);
//$postdata = 'dplLanguage=fa&txtUsername=&txtPassword=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTEwMDM5MDE3NDUPZBYEZg8VARJTYWZhcmFmYXJpbi1TZXBlaHJkAgEPZBYEAgUPEA8WAh4LXyFEYXRhQm91bmRnZGRkZAINDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaBYCZg9kFgJmDxUBE9io2K7YtNmG2KfZhdmHINmH2KdkZMdboHK0C5vwU/0H8jDKN8JIUGAWK7y6psPERPkF/dYP&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBwLVs6iwDQKl1bK4CQK1qbSRCwLHlbuRCALGla+RCAKC3IeGDAKqs9XKA+XnuPlm+7BeBMKdG9tnXAq2MVVFKjVmbCbQG4g9jB9u';
$postdata = $posts;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

$rnd = rand(2547896321456987, 9999999999999999);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$a = curl_exec ($ch);
$url= 'http://www.example.com/search.aspx';

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$a = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

If I don't send the variables __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION, Page returns to login screen.
But when I use this vars I see this error: 
     Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

Comment: As the error message says, your base64 data is invalid. Rather than specifying static strings, you should specify the original data and pass it through `base64_encode()`. Did you trim some `=` off the end of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($aPosts as $key => $value){
    $posts .= $key . "=" . urlencode($value) . "&";
}
$posts = trim($posts, "=");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Replace your foreach by this function :

```
http_build_query($aPosts);
```